# How to put individual STD_LOGIC bits as arguments instead of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR

Tags: vhdl

I have this entity:

```
ENTITY example IS PORT 
( 
    x: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
    y: OUT STD_LOGIC
);
END ENTITY example;
```

When I call it, I do:

```
g1:  ENTITY work.example(method) PORT MAP (x(0) => a, x(1) => b, y => c);
```

but I want a neat way to do it like:

```
g1  ENTITY work.example(method) PORT MAP ( (a,b) , c );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. VHDL -2008 should be able to do so (actual expressions are not widely supported by FPGA vendors nor all simulators). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses. If not supported you'd need an intermediary signal.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Concatenate. `PORT MAP ( b&a , c );`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help, it worked, can you answer my question so I can choose your answer as the correct one?

Comment: Please always keep the language reference manual (LRM) of VHDL on hand at all times